# Decimal Precision keeps changing on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to work with Decimal objects in my Notebook, but when I set the precision on one cell, it is not preserved on the other. For example:

```
from decimal import *
```

---

```
getcontext().prec = 6

Decimal(1)/Decimal(7)

[out]: Decimal('0.142857')
```

Which is what I want. But if I run in different cells:

```
getcontext().prec = 6
```

---

```
Decimal(1)/Decimal(7)

[out]: Decimal('0.1428571428571428571428571429')
```

Is it possible to preserve the same precision value across different cells?

Comment: I have notebook server version: 5.7.8 and using python 3.6. I am able to preserve the same precision value across different cells. What is your notebook server version and python version?

Comment: My notebook's version is 6.0.0, and Python's 3.7.4

Comment: I am not able to replicate your behavior. You should try one more time after stopping and restarting the kernel.