# Trying to set precision with the decimal package but unable to obtain desired precision

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, decimal, jupyter

[image: jupyter nb]I'm playing around with the decimal package in Python and wondering why the precision I'm setting is not implemented as desired.  For example:

```
from decimal import *
getcontext()

Context(prec=28, rounding=ROUND_HALF_EVEN, Emin=-999999, Emax=999999, capitals=1, clamp=0, flags=[], traps=[InvalidOperation, DivisionByZero, Overflow])


getcontext().prec = 2
getcontext()

Context(prec=2, rounding=ROUND_HALF_EVEN, Emin=-999999, Emax=999999, capitals=1, clamp=0, flags=[], traps=[InvalidOperation, DivisionByZero, Overflow])

Decimal(1)/Decimal(9)
Decimal('0.1111111111111111111111111111')
```

I was expecting that the output from the line Decimal(1)/Decimal(9) would be Decimal('0.11') rather than Decimal('0.1111111111111111111111111111'). What am I missing?

Comment: Probably because 1/9 is 0.11 repeating

Comment: @Shidouuu why should that matter?  If there are cases where the precision is ignored then it doesn't make sense to have a limit in the first place.

Comment: How are you running it? I just tried it in a REPL and got your desired output, `Decimal('0.11')`. And it's weird that the input and output are appearing together in your snippet.

Comment: Check `getcontext().prec` at the end. Has it actually changed?

Comment: @wjandrea I'm running in a jupyter notebook.  I just copied and pasted the cells from the notebook into this thread.  If there's a better way to represent the input and output, let me know.  Also, the output from 'getcontext().prec'  is represented in the third from the last line above.  As you can see 'prec' is 2 so it has changed.

Comment: @jgg Did you maybe run the cells out of order? Try doing "Run all". And yes, I can see that `getcontext().prec` has changed *there*, but I'm saying try it again *after* the calculation and make sure that it's actually changed, i.e. add a cell, put `getcontext().prec`, and run it.

Comment: @wjandrea Cells were run in order,  Added an attachment with a screenshot of the JN.

Comment: @wjandrea Also ran the same lines in iPython and was able to produce the desired results.  Something funky going on with my JN but unable to disentangle.

Comment: Interesting; I can reproduce here. It seems that a fresh context is used in each cell; I haven't yet figured out why. This may have something to do with [PEP 550](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0550/)

Comment: Sorry, [PEP 567](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0567/), not PEP 550. And indeed I get the expected behaviour (a result of `0.11`) with Python 3.6, but not with Python 3.8, after the introduction of context variables and the modification of the `decimal` module to use those context variables. At a guess, Jupyter executes each cell as a separate `asyncio` task, so the context changes in one cell don't affect later cells.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57836837/270986, https://stackoverflow.com/q/59851290/270986 and https://github.com/ipython/ipykernel/issues/494

Comment: This seems to be the most directly relevant and useful bug report: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/11565

Comment: @MarkDickinson Thank you.  Was able to obtain the desired result after placing the  '''getcontext().prec = 2''' and '''Decimal(1)/Decimal(9)''' in the same cell.